# Example TIPS and how inflation rate affects its principal

Tags: united-states, inflation, tips

Taken from [here](https://www.thebalance.com/how-do-tips-work-417128).

> Say the Treasury issues an inflation-protected security with a $1,000 face value and a 3 percent coupon. In the first year, the investor receives $30 in two semiannual payments. That year, the CPI increases by 4 percent. As a result, the face value adjusts upward to $1,040.
>
> In Year 2, the investor receives the same 3 percent coupon but this time it’s based on the new, adjusted face value of $1,040. The result: instead of receiving an interest payment of $30, the investor receives interest of $31.20 (.03 times $1,040). In Year 3, inflation drops to 2 percent. The face value rises from $1,040 to $1060.80, and the investor receives interest of $31.82.

I'm mostly confused about this line `In Year 3, inflation drops to 2 percent. The face value rises from $1,040 to $1060.80, and the investor receives interest of $31.82.` Without knowing what the inflation rate was previous to "drop[ing] to 2 percent", how is the change in the principal of this TIPS calculated in this example?

Comment: But the previous inflation rate is known. It is 4%. The CPI is an index that tracks inflation. Saying the CPI increased by 4 percent is the same as saying that the rate of inflation is 4%.

Comment: @Acccumulation yes this was my confusion. I didn’t realized CPI and inflation rate could be taken synonymously. Thank you for clearing it up!

Comment: @Jalep Strictly, CPI _itself_ and the inflation rate are not synonymous: rather, the rate of inflation is (roughly) the _change_ in the value of CPI over a given period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the example, the inflation *during* year 2 (and measured at the beginning of year 3) was 2 percent. During year 1 it was 4 percent.

2 percent of $1,040 is $20.80. When you add the $20.80 to the previous face value of $1,040 you get $1,060.80.